# Problema en mostrar la fecha del dia siguiente al cambiar de año

Tags: java, revisión-de-código, calendar

Supongamos que ingreso 31/12/2010, el primer messageDialog imprime 31/13/2010, pero el segundo imprime la fecha correcta que es 01/01/2011.
Lo unico que requiero es que cuando diciembre sea 31 imprima  "MessageDialog(null,"la fecha de mañana es "+dia_siguiente+" / "+mes_siguiente+" / "+año_siguiente);" y cuando sea menor a 31 sea "MessageDialog(null,"la fecha de mañana es "+dia_siguiente+" / "+mes_siguiente+" / "+año);"
Es el unico fallo que me presenta, el codigo está incompleto (falta febrero) pero mi problema es la doble impresion al cambio de año

```
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
     //Declaracion de variables
     int dia=0, mes=0, año=0, dia_siguiente=0, mes_siguiente=0, año_siguiente=0;
     String var="";
     var=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el dia");
     dia=Integer.parseInt(var);
     var=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el mes");
     mes=Integer.parseInt(var);
     var=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el año");
     año=Integer.parseInt(var);
     if(dia>30 && (mes==4 || mes==6 || mes==9 || mes==11)||dia>31 && (mes==1 || mes==3 || mes==5 || mes==7 || mes==8 || mes==10 || mes==12))
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No puede haber mas de esos dias en dicho mes");
     }
        else
        {
           if(dia==30 && (mes==4 || mes==6 || mes==9 || mes==11)||dia==31 && (mes==1 || mes==3 || mes==5 || mes==7 || mes==8 || mes==10 || mes==12))
           {
              mes_siguiente=mes+1; //se aumenta uno si el dia termina en ultimo del mes (30 o 31)
              dia_siguiente=1; //se comienza con el mes siguiente en dia 1
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la fecha de mañana es "+dia_siguiente+" / "+mes_siguiente+" / "+año);
           }
           else
           {
              dia_siguiente=dia+1; //en caso de que no, solo aumenta un dia
              mes_siguiente=mes; //el mes sigue siendo el mismo
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la fecha de mañana es "+dia_siguiente+" / "+mes_siguiente+" / "+año);
           }
        }
           if(dia_siguiente==1 && mes_siguiente==13)
           {
              mes_siguiente=1;
              año_siguiente=año+1;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"la fecha de mañana es "+dia_siguiente+" / "+mes_siguiente+" / "+año_siguiente);

           }
           else
           {
              año_siguiente=año;
           } 
     }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Para el mes siguiente:

```
    int mes_siguiente= 12;
    mes_siguiente= ((mes_siguiente+1)%12);
    System.out.println(mes_siguiente);
```

> Por otro lado podes usar la clase Calendar que viene con Java.

```
  //mm-1 porque considera a Enero como mes 0;
   Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar(2019,12-1,31);
   int año = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   int mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

   System.out.println(dia+"/"+(mes+1)+"/"+año);
   //Siguiente mes los seteo
   calendario.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia+1);
   año = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   System.out.println(dia+"/"+(mes+1)+"/"+año);
```